# Certificate Error when using wikipedia API in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate, python-3.7, wikipedia-api

When I'm trying to use the Wikipedia API, I get a certificate error message.

This for an assistant I am coding on a school computer and I think it is something that has been put there by administration as I got a certificate error when using NPM previously.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    wikiSearch = query.strip("wiki ")
    outputs = wikipedia.summary(wikiSearch, sentences=3)
```

I thought this would return the first three sentences of the article as it does in python 2.7 but instead returns this lengthy error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 350, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 355, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 853, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /w/api.php?list=search&srprop=&srlimit=1&limit=1&srsearch=alex&srinfo=suggestion&format=json&action=query (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dave.py", line 54, in <module>
    index()
  File "dave.py", line 24, in index
    outputs = wikipedia.summary(wikiSearch, sentences=3)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/wikipedia/util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 231, in summary
    page_info = page(title, auto_suggest=auto_suggest, redirect=redirect)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 270, in page
    results, suggestion = search(title, results=1, suggestion=True)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/wikipedia/util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 103, in search
    raw_results = _wiki_request(search_params)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 737, in _wiki_request
    r = requests.get(API_URL, params=params, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 668, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 668, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 247, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /w/api.php?list=search&srprop=&srlimit=1&limit=1&srsearch=alex&srinfo=suggestion&format=json&action=query (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

Edit:

I now get this error:

```
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Desktop/Dave/dave.py", line 84, in <module>
    index()
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Desktop/Dave/dave.py", line 26, in index
    outputs = wikipedia.summary(wikiSearch, sentences=3)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/wikipedia/util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 231, in summary
    page_info = page(title, auto_suggest=auto_suggest, redirect=redirect)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 270, in page
    results, suggestion = search(title, results=1, suggestion=True)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/wikipedia/util.py", line 28, in __call__
    ret = self._cache[key] = self.fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 103, in search
    raw_results = _wiki_request(search_params)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 737, in _wiki_request
    r = requests.get(API_URL, params=params, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexander.hawking/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='myproxy.proxy.com', port=1234): Max retries exceeded with url: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?list=search&srprop=&srlimit=1&limit=1&srsearch=alex&srinfo=suggestion&format=json&action=query (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10e2d3eb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known')))
```

Comment: Which wikipedia library are you using?

Comment: This one: https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/

Comment: it's most likely because your administration might have set up a proxy which is causing SSL error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you encountered a similar error when you were working with NPM, it's most likely due to the proxy setup by your administration.

You can configure the proxy for any third party module to connect to the internet. By default, `urlopen` of urllib3 uses the environment variable `http_proxy` to determine which HTTP proxy to use.

run this command in CMD before running your python application

```
export http_proxy='http://myproxy.proxy.com:1234'
```

============================================================

if you don't know your proxy you can try this workaround.
run this command in CMD before running the python application

```
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=''
```

or add these lines to your code to avoid adding environment variable manually every time.

```
import os
os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = ""
```

if you are getting InsecureRequestWarning and you want to suppress it you can do the following.

```
import wikipedia
import os
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
os.environ['CURL_CA_BUNDLE'] = ""
os.environ['PYTHONWARNINGS']="ignore:Unverified HTTPS request"
print(wikipedia.wikipedia.summary("Google"))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: when I try that I get this error:     raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: http://myproxy.proxy.com:1234python3

Comment: You have to replace it with proxy of your organisation.

Comment: how do I find that?

Comment: You have to talk to your administration for details of proxy

Comment: I am on a mac and when I go in proxy settings there doesn't appear to be anything as shown [here](https://imgur.com/mU9U62V)

Comment: By putting that in terminal ^ btw

Comment: if this solves your problem please upvote and accept it so it helps other users who visit your question :) 
have a good day